# How many instances are kept for an element in two different collections?

Tags: java, collections

If I have an instance of MyClass, let's call it myElement, and I add it to two lists, or queues, or maps or whatever. How many times will it be saved in memory ?

```
MyClass myElement = new MyClass();

List<MyClass> list1  = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
PriorityQueue<MyClass> queue1 = new PriorityQueue<MyClass>();

list1.add(myElement);
queue1.add(myElement);
```

Will I have it saved only once and both lists elements point to that location in memory ? Or will I have it saved twice ?

Comment: There is only one instance. You are adding a reference to each list.

Answer (score 7):

No matter to how many list's you are adding, there is only one instance.

In short same instance. So only one.

Answer (score 0):

you are pushing reference of the class. it will always point to the same memory location wherever you are pushing.

only single instance will be exist.